# How can I solve this problem in basic CSS (style a table)?

Tags: html, css

I tried to solve it by myself but unfortunately, it didn't work.

The task is, that I have to write a CSS code for a given html-code (with table) and it has to look like that (see picture). I tried to use margin and padding, but it didn't work.

[image]

Code:

```css
.tableC  tr:first-of-type{

    
    height: 200px;
    width: 40%;
    background-color: #f5ff58;

    
}

.tableC  tr td.AC{
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 50px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
}

.tableC  tr td.AA, td.AB{
    border: 3px solid black;
}

.BA, .BB{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 30px 60px 30px 0px; 
}

.tableC  tr:nth-of-type(3){
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border: 3px solid black;

}

.BC {
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 60px 60px 60px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="table_pictures">
            <h3> Lorem Ipsum dolor </h3>
            <table class="tableC">
                <tr>
                    <td class="AA" rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
                    </td>
                    <td class="AB" rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
                    </td>
                    <td class="AC"> nur eine Zeile
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="BA"> nur eine Zeile
                    </td>
                    <td class="BB"> nur eine Zeile 
                    </td>
                    <td class="BC"rowspan="2"> Über zwei Zeilen
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. **Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question**."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works but you have not given the rows a height so that the empty rows look like they don't exist.

I've created a minimal example for you to explore in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-rowspan-k98c3i?file=/index.html). This should make clear how `rowspan` works to achieve your desired result.

Following the code. Mind how I give the row a height so that it becomes visible:

```css
tr {
  height: 40px;
}

td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem Ipsum dolor</h3>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">Über zwei Zeilen</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Über zwei Zeilen</td>
          <td>nur eine Zeile</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>nur eine Zeile</td>
          <td>nur eine Zeile</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Über zwei Zeilen</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```